# How to get the selected-row count from a list box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
int countSelected = ListBoxMembers.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Count();
       string groupName = txt_GroupName.Text;


       for (int counter = 0; counter < ListBoxMembers.Items.Count; counter++)
```

I have 20 items in the list, when I select only 2 ListBoxMembers.Items.Count shouws 20  and Countselected is 0

i tried this int count = ListBoxMembers.GetSelectedIndices().length;
system.web.ui.controls.listbox does not contain a definition for selected items and no extension method selevted items acceptin first argument error

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxMembers" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="style102"
                                   ToolTip="Press ctrl to select multiple users" DataValueField="FirstName"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: what is your platform? asp.net? silverlight? WPF? etc.

Comment: `ListItem` is asp.NET at least

Comment: `Length` with a capital **L** [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the functionality built-in to the ListBox ... no Linq required. (For WinForms)

```
int countSelected = ListBoxMembers.SelectedItems.Count;
```

Edit: (since the OP added to the question and it appears it is regarding ASP.NET)

```
int countSelected = 0;
foreach(ListItem li in ListBoxMembers.Items)
    if(li.Selected)
        countSelected++;
```

I'm not sure why the Linq statement is not working. It certainly appears that it should be... is there any difference if you explicitly include true? `i => i.Selected == true`

Comment: What namespace to use for that in c#

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct, but you can try this:

```
int count = ListBoxMembers.GetSelectedIndices().Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

there should be somehting like listBoxMembers.SelectedItems which returns a list of the selected items.  So you could do listBoxMembers.SelectedItems.count.  Now this is in VB.Net but there should be something like it for C#

Comment: aww you beat me to it grant.  :)